# Preference of rafidha over kaafir asli

Tags: sunnah, sects, kuffar, ibn-taymiyyah

السلام عليكم
I recently came across a statement of sheikh ul islam رحمه الله regarding someone who prefers the kuffar asli over the rafidha, he رحمه الله says that it is not right to prefer kuffar asli over a rafidhi (majmu fatawa vol35 pg201), can someone shed some light in this matter?
جزاك الله خيرا